# Roots of Unity, Curtis's rep theory text

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

I've been reading Curtis's rep theory text and I run across a statement he claims that I don't know how to show it.  I highlighted the statement below.
[image]

I feel like I don't see it because I'm missing some elementary properties about LCM.
Thank you all.

Comment: In particular, it seems true that the product of the primitive $h_i$th roots of $1$ is a primitive $q$th root of unity (assuming you restrict to relatively prime $h_i$ and if two $h_i$ are are similar prime powers, $h_i = p^n$ and $h_j = p^m$, then you use whichever one has the largest power of the prime). For example, if $e_3$ is a primtive $3$rd root of unity and $e_{25}$ is a primitive $25$th root of unity, then $e_3 e_{25}$ is a primitive $75$th root of unity. Why? Let $\omega$ be the primitive $75$th root of 1; $\omega^{25} = e_3$ and $\omega^3 = e_{25}$, and $e_3e_{25} = \omega^{28}$.

Comment: (Where in my comment above, by "primitive" $k$th root I mean the exact primitive $k$th root $e^{2 \pi i / k}$ frequently.)

Comment: @davidlowryduda thank you for your comment, by what you said, I think I see why now, since roots of unity are generated by primitive root and the $q$ primitive root is the product of of all the $h_i$ primitive roots, it follows that $q$ root of unity are product of $h_i$ roots.  Is that correct???